# What does mapping within discriminator do in Swagger?

Tags: rest, swagger, documentation, openapi

The [explanation in the doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) is not clear for me. And I see no difference after my api doc renders.
What the difference visually? At what mapping do logically?
For example

```yaml
MySchema:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/componets/schemas/SubSchema1'
    - $ref: '#/componets/schemas/SubSchema2'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: some_property:
    mapping:
      TypeA: '#/componets/schemas/SubSchema1'
      TypeB: '#/componets/schemas/SubSchema2'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you use [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io) it won't be much of a difference. I use [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) if I want to validate discriminator.

Lets take a example:
You want to convert a reading to your preferred unit of measurement (which is `usStandard`)
Your request object may be looking like this -

```json
{
  "value": 7,
  "unitOfMeasure": {
    "type": "distance",
    "value": "km"
  }
}
```

So After conversion your API will return

```json
{
  "value": 4.3496,
  "unitOfMeasure": {
    "type": "distance",
    "value": "mi"
  }
}
```

So depending upon your unit of measurement type you have to use different schema.
if `type` is

1. `distance` then possible values `km` and `mi`
2. `volume` then possible values `L` and `gal`

So your OpenAPI spec your discriminator will use type property to determine which schema to use. Note: in that case type will be a required property within each schema.

This is same as jackson's type

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
    property = "type",
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
public abstract class UOM {
}

@JsonTypeName("distance")
public class DistanceUOM extends UOM {
}
```

And jackson will use type to determine in which class it should de-serialize to.

---

Created a github gist with this usecase [See Here](https://gist.github.com/snigdhasjg/3b07e1bb1a58658c92ef6904055067e5)

So how [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) will render this (See there is one drop-down to select type)

**Type: distance**

[image]

**Type: volume**

[image]